# Passing form values on PHP same page

Tags: php, forms

I have a form in my page and also have different phps  in the same page..how can i pass the form to one of the phps? Thank you

It goes like this.

```
<form action = 'samepage.php' 
method='POST'>
<input>
<input type = 'submit'>
</form>
<?php 
?>
<?php 
?>
<?php
I want to pass the value here
?>
```

Comment: you have to set first a form input name then read it via $_POST, and removing the action will make it post to itself

Comment: once you POST the form whatever values there were in the form are available throughout that page. The `input` needs a `name` and can be accessed using `$_POST['name_of_field']`

Comment: Keep in mind that all php blocks are always executed in order, one after another. I think that described approach is not the best one. I'd separate this php file into several separate ones.

Answer (score 1):

The form in HTML page is a structure that allow you to insert some value and then can be passed to the backend with a specific HTTP Method called as GET,POST,PUT, DELETE etc.

Here an example:

```
// HTML Page. index.html
<form action="page.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit">

// page.php
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];

echo "Your username is: " . $username;
?>
```